# how can I save measurementUnits correctly Imperial (F)", "Metric (C) in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, savestate

I am developing a weather application and I want to save measurementUnits in SettingsScreen user can choose Imperial Fahrenheit or Metric Celsius after choosing one of this user  click save button it has to save it unfortunately it is not working what I want to know where I am making mistake

below my SettingsScreen.kt where I have tried implemented measurement units logic

```
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen(navController: NavController,
                   settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {

    var unitToggleState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val measurementUnits = listOf("Imperial (F)", "Metric (C)")
    val choiceFromDb = settingsViewModel.unitList.collectAsState().value

    val defaultChoice = if (choiceFromDb.isNullOrEmpty()) measurementUnits[0] else choiceFromDb[0].unit

    var choiceState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(defaultChoice)
    }

    Scaffold(topBar = {
        WeatherAppBar(
            title = "Settings",
            icon = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
            false,
            navController = navController){
            navController.popBackStack()
        }
    }) {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()) {
            Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                Text(
                    text = "Change Units of Measurement",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 15.dp)
                )

                IconToggleButton(checked = !unitToggleState ,
                    onCheckedChange = {
                        unitToggleState = !it
                        choiceState = if (unitToggleState) {
                            "Imperial (F)"
                        } else {
                            "Metric (C)"
                        }
                        Log.d("TAG", "MainContent: $unitToggleState")

                    }, modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
                        .clip(shape = RectangleShape)
                        .padding(5.dp)
                        .background(Color.Magenta.copy(alpha = 0.4f))) {

                    Text(text = if (unitToggleState) "Fahrenheit ºF" else "Celsius ºC" )


                }
                Button(onClick = {
                    settingsViewModel.deleteAllUnits()
                    settingsViewModel.insertUnit(Unit(unit = choiceState
                    ))

                },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(3.dp)
                        .align(CenterHorizontally),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(34.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                        backgroundColor = Color(0xFFEFBE42)
                    )) {
                    Text(text = "Save",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                        color = Color.White,
                        fontSize = 17.sp)

                }


            }
        }


    }

}
```

and below SettinsViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: WeatherDbRepository
): ViewModel() {
    private val _unitList = MutableStateFlow<List<Unit>>(emptyList())
    val unitList = _unitList.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.getUnits().distinctUntilChanged()
                .collect { listOfUnits ->
                    if (listOfUnits.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        repository.insertUnit(Unit("unit"))

                    }else {
                        _unitList.value = listOfUnits

                    }

                }

        }
    }

    fun insertUnit(unit: Unit) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.insertUnit(unit) }
    fun updateUnit(unit: Unit) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.updateUnit(unit) }
    fun deleteUnit(unit: Unit) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.deleteUnit(unit) }
    fun deleteAllUnits() = viewModelScope.launch { repository.deleteAllUnits() }


}
```

and below MainScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    city: String
) {
    val curCity: String = if (city.isBlank()) "Stockholm" else city
    val unitFromDb = settingsViewModel.unitList.collectAsState().value
    var unit by remember {
        mutableStateOf("imperial")
    }
    var isImperial by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    if (!unitFromDb.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        unit = unitFromDb[0].unit.split(" ")[0].lowercase()
        isImperial = unit == "imperial"

        val weatherData = produceState<DataOrException<Weather, Boolean, Exception>>(
            initialValue = DataOrException(loading = true)
        ) {
            value = mainViewModel.getWeatherData(
                city = curCity,
                units = unit
            )
        }.value

        if (weatherData.loading == true) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        } else if (weatherData.data != null) {
            MainScaffold(
                weather = weatherData.data!!, navController,
                isImperial = isImperial
            )

        }

    }


}

@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun MainScaffold(
    weather: Weather, navController: NavController, isImperial: Boolean
) {

    Scaffold(topBar = {
        WeatherAppBar(
            title = weather.city.name + " ,${weather.city.country}",
            navController = navController,
            onAddActionClicked = {
                navController.navigate(WeatherScreens.SearchScreen.name)


            },
            elevation = 5.dp
        ) {
            Log.d("TAG", "MainScaffold: Button Clicked")
        }

    }) {
        MainContent(data = weather, isImperial = isImperial)

    }
}

@Composable
fun MainContent(data: Weather, isImperial: Boolean) {
    val weatherItem = data.list[0]
    val imageUrl = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${weatherItem.weather[0].icon}.png"

    Column(
        Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Text(
            text = formatDate(weatherItem.dt), // Wed Nov 30
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSecondary,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp)
        )

        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(4.dp)
                .size(200.dp),
            shape = CircleShape,
            color = Color(0xFFFFC400)
        ) {

            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                WeatherStateImage(imageUrl = imageUrl)
                Text(
                    text = formatDecimals(weatherItem.temp.day) + "º",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold
                )
                Text(
                    text = weatherItem.weather[0].main,
                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic
                )
            }
        }
        HumidityWindPressureRow(weather = data.list[0], isImperial = isImperial)
        Divider()
        SunsetSunRiseRow(weather = data.list[0])
        Text(
            "This Week",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )

        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            color = Color(0xFFEEF1EF),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 14.dp)
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(1.dp)
            ) {
                items(items = data.list) { item: WeatherItem ->
                    WeatherDetailRow(weather = item)

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I want to know where exactly I am making mistake any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share SettingsViewModel and Activity code

Comment: @UmairKhalid I shared SettingsViewModel.kt code please check it

Comment: first request, please move your business logic out of your composable and move it to your viewmodels

Comment: @UmairKhalid I did not understand what you mean I am new to compose I am following tutorial

Comment: any calculation or decision which you are making composable is anti-pattern and should be  moved out of composable and should be in usecases or viewmodels, Composable should be a simple composable listening to state

Comment: for example 

unit = unitFromDb[0].unit.split(" ")[0].lowercase()
        isImperial = unit == "imperial"

this should be moved to viewmodel

Comment: @UmairKhalid I will gonna do that wha was problem do you think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253122/discussion-between-edgar-and-umair-khalid).